# how to count number of instances of a subclass in python?

Tags: python, django, class, django-models, subclass

I am trying to create a website where you can play songs from different albums.
I think everything is working fine but I'm stuck with just one thing. In the details of the album I also wanted to display number of songs it contains.

Here are my models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, User
from django.db import models


class Album(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.FileField()
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title + ' - ' + self.artist


class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    audio_file = models.FileField(default='')
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

How to display number of songs in album details?

Comment: This has nothing to do with subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate the number of songs in the current queryset you're using to retrieve the albums:

```
from django.db.models import Count

album_qs = Album.objects.filter(...) # your queryset
album_qs = album_qs.annotate(num_of_songs=Count('song'))
```

`num_of_songs` will be accessible by each object in the queryset, just like any of the other model fields:

```
for album in album_qs:
    print(album.artist)
    print(album.num_of_songs) # use-case
```

---

Reference:

**https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/**